# my ArrayAdapter doesn't display another string in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

This is the first time I make a ListView using an ArrayAdapter.

But I don't know how to display the 2nd string (A,B,C...)?

I think I must be adding something in the main java file but I' not sure what it to add?

Here is my current code:

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;

   public class equipements extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_equipements);
    String[] tools_names = {"1" , "2" , "3" , "4" , "5" };
    String[] tools_def = {"A" , "B" , "C" , "D" , "E" };
    ListAdapter testAdapter = new eq_custom_adapter(this , tools_names);
    ListAdapter testAdapter1 = new eq_custom_adapter(this , tools_def);
    ListView test = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.eq_listView);
    test.setAdapter(testAdapter);
    test.setAdapter(testAdapter1);
}}
```

and here's my adapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

class eq_custom_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{


eq_custom_adapter(Context context,String [] tools) {
    super(context,R.layout.equipments_view ,tools);
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView,  ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater1 =  LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View customView = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.equipments_view , parent , false);

    String tool = getItem(position);
    String tool_defs = getItem(position);
    TextView tool_name = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.tool_name);
    TextView tool_def = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.tool_def);
    ImageView tool_image = (ImageView) 
    customView.findViewById(R.id.tool_image);

    tool_name.setText(tool);
    tool_def.setText(tool_defs);
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            tool_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.a);
            break;
        case 1:
            tool_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.b);
            break;
        case 2:
            tool_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.c);
            break;
        case 3:
            tool_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.d);
        case 4:
            tool_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.e);
            break;
    }
    return customView;
}
```

Comment: Reworded to make it easier to read; improved code indenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need 2 adapters you just need 1. So change the code like its shown below -

```
String[] tools_names = {"1" , "2" , "3" , "4" , "5" };
String[] tools_def = {"A" , "B" , "C" , "D" , "E" };
ListAdapter testAdapter = new eq_custom_adapter(this , tools_names);
ListView test = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.eq_listView);
test.setAdapter(testAdapter);
```

This will set your adapter to array. Ideally it is not advised to ahve 2 arrays populating one adapter. So you should have array of custom objects. But for this scenario I will explain how you can do it. Change your `getView` method like below -

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView,  ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater1 =  LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View customView = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.equipments_view , parent , false);


String tool = tools_names[position]; // change here to get from 1st array
String tool_defs = tools_def[position]; // change here to get from 2nd array
TextView tool_name = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.tool_name);
TextView tool_def = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.tool_def);
ImageView tool_image = (ImageView) 
customView.findViewById(R.id.tool_image);

tool_name.setText(tool);
tool_def.setText(tool_defs);
switch (position) {
    case 0:
        tool_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.a);
        break;
    case 1:
        tool_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.b);
        break;
    case 2:
        tool_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.c);
        break;
    case 3:
        tool_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.d);
    case 4:
        tool_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.e);
        break;
}
return customView;
}
```

**Better way for future:** 
As I said earlier, ideally you shouldn't do it this way. If you have multiple data to show create a class like -

```
class Tool{
String toolName;
String toolDef;
 int toolImageId;

 public String getToolName() {
     return toolName;
 }

 public void setToolName(String toolName) {
     this.toolName = toolName;
 }

 public String getToolDef() {
     return toolDef;
 }

 public void setToolDef(String toolDef) {
     this.toolDef = toolDef;
 }

 public int getToolImageId() {
     return toolImageId;
 }

 public void setToolImageId(int toolImageId) {
     this.toolImageId = toolImageId;
 }
 }
```

Then create an Array of objects of this class and then populate your listview from it. You can get lot of tutorials on Google about this.

Comment: sorry but to what should i change the to get rom the array ?

Comment: You are getting from first array in get view method in my code in line String tool = tools_names[position];

Comment: Glad I could help